# CSS padding looks different per graphics card

Tags: html, css, graphics, padding

After reseting the margin and padding values for each browser, there still seems to be an issue with the padding. I think this is because of the graphics card. AMD/NVidia cards render the content much nicer and appropriate than Intel Integrated HD cards. Is there any way of fixing this?

Using Firefox the padding is perfect. IE and chrome are about 2 pixels off.
Using Intel cards the padding is also off. As I reset all margins and paddings, it cannot be browser related.

Long story short, is there any way to make all graphics cards render the content equally?

Any help is much appreciated!

Update:
I am using one computer with switchable graphics. AMD/Intel
here is a screenshot of a sample:
http://bayimg.com/CaONBAAdj

Code sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fyvb/

Comment: I've never heard of a problem where a graphic card makes a difference in rendering CSS. It's very likely to be something else. Could you show us your code? Make a testcase?

Comment: What's the smallest amount of code the reproduce the issue? Just click [edit] and add it to your post. I've never heard of this either, all the testing was done on a single machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are you resetting your paddings and margins ?

margin:0; padding:0

you may also have display:block to consider and line:height to consider resetting.

try this css reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ on a test page and make some  compares with ...

```
<div>
```

..tags set at various heights and widths

Comment: glad you got sorted, ps: line:height:1 is not quite right ( semantically) ( 1 of what? ) try 100%